# Is there any JSON viewer to open large json files (windows)?

Tags: json, viewer, json-view, large-data

I have very large JSON file which is of several GB. I am looking for any efficient JSON viewer. In which we are also able to view JSON in tree format.

I understand such huge file can't be loaded in one go. I wonder is there any software to view JSON in parts (i.e opening ~10k records) at a time?

Comment: You could (not sure) use MongoDb to store it an d query it

Comment: How large is it and how much RAM do you have? I'm currently working on [Huge JSON viewer](http://development.wellisolutions.de/huge-json-viewer/)

Comment: On Windows I used Notepad++ to load a 468MB JSON. The loading took some minutes. Then I formatted the single line JSON with the JSON Viewer Plugin. When additionally setting the read-only mode for the file, then scrolling though the 26 million lines is quite fast.

Comment: Main problem is when the JSON is all on a single line.  Use jq to format it first, then open that: `jq . < bigline.json > formatted.json`.  For me, this solved the problem in most editors.

Comment: Have you tried https://viewer.dadroit.com/ is fast and light.

Comment: My AV is showing it as virus

Comment: Dadroit is a brilliant tool that treats JSON as a data format, not plain text. It provides you with a quick outline view with the help of tree representation of JSON data from root to last nodes. You can browse and query JSON like an enterprise DBMS. You can get it here https://dadroit.com/

Comment: Dadroit should be the accepted answer.  It is much faster than the others and shows the data in a readable format

Comment: Until recently, I would have considered dadroit the answer too. Unfortunately, their latest release redacts files above 50MB, i.e. part of the data is blacked out. Really annoying!

Answer (score 23):

If you're using Mac, try [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/). Loads large files super fast. Just disable the hex view and you'll get a regular-ish editor.

Comment: Thanks! Works super well on 800MB file :)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Works well on 500MB files. Any way to get Hex Fiend to format the JSON?

Comment: This was an awesome answer. Would never have thought of using Hex Fiend for this.

Comment: Opened up my 25GB JSON file in mere milliseconds.

Comment: @Badrush good that it isn't  marked as answer as mac only!

Answer (score 20):

You can try [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/). Its quite good in handling large files:

Comment: I haven't done much empirical testing, but in my experience, Sublime seems to struggle with minified files. It handles large files with many reasonably short lines passably, but it chokes on a 50 MB JSON one-liner.

Comment: In my experience, Sublime has to chug for a while before it can finally open large files. I just opened a 50MB JSON file in Sublime and it took several minutes before the file appeared in the editor.

Comment: been sitting here for 20 or 25 minutes waiting for sublime to open this geoJSON file.... 120MB

Comment: For a 5MB file, I just open the Chrome console and do `x = {"huge_json": "asdf"}`

Comment: Works for a 15 MB file that made VS Code's extension manager crash and is very sluggish in Notepad++.

Comment: Dadroit is a brilliant tool that treats JSON as a data format, not plain text. It provides you with a quick outline view with the help of tree representation of JSON data from root to last nodes. You can browse and query JSON like an enterprise DBMS. You can get it here dadroit.com

Comment: Try this https://github.com/WelliSolutions/HugeJsonViewer

Comment: @PointNetworks Post that as an answer, or I will.  It opens 370 MB single-line json file in seconds and displays it in a readable format.

Comment: @LordDarthVader It takes a very long time to open a 370 MB file.

Comment: No This tool freezes and falls over. Notepad is better

Answer (score 4):

I've used [JSONViewer](https://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) to view large files (over 100Mb). It's not all that fast at loading them, but it gets there eventually.

Comment: Unpopular solution but Works like charm : Try out *nano* if you are using Linux. It will read only that part of the file which is displayed on the terminal. Loads super fast!! and does not blow up memory requirement. 

If you are good at python just use file.read() option to parse only that part you need

Unpopular solution but Works like charm : Try out *nano* if you are using Linux. It will read only that part of the file which is displayed on the terminal. Loads super fast!! and does not blow up memory requirement. 
If you are good at python just use file.read() option to parse only

Comment: Just tried it and it is decades away from "fast". Honestly, after 15 minutes of waiting I believe it entirely froze to death. My test scenario: HP Elitebook 745 G2 with Win 10 Pro and 4GB DDR3, SSD HDD (1TB) - Notepad++ opened it way faster. Everything was shown in one row only but it did the job in my case as I only needed to search for a contained string. Maybe this comment saves somebody some time.

Comment: Link not working anymore, where it can be found?

Comment: This link is an updated link at github
https://github.com/justaprogrammer/JsonViewer
It somehow has done the job for me